# Cordova and Jquery Post to codeigniter RESTapi

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm making a cordova application.
I made two simple form to login and register.
I use jquery to POST all data to my CI's controller (http://example.com/api/register for example)

Everythings works fine until i try to validate the data with CI.

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    // some code
}
```

I tried to use the form_validation library but it seems that to use it properly, i need to load a form in codeigniter first. My problem is here, i can't load a form in CI because i'm in a cordova application.
How can i use CI form_validation library without loading a form first?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you load the form_validation library first? and don't forget to use POST instead of PUT

Comment: yes, in the __construct function, maybe i should move it to the index function?